# Unity2D How to make Ai run random directions

Tags: unity-game-engine

there's some tutorial in youtube but i think it's not the right thing why?
yeah the ai do run in random directions but the animation does not. even the ai is moving its still on idle animation. does someone have a source code or idea to make it work the way it should be? please help me im stuck in this thing for a week now. 
have tried everything I can but it all fails please lend me a hand on this one im begging you. i only have 1more day to finish the basic game im creating for our school midterm exam. i dont want to failed T_T

```
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;

    public bool isWalking;

    public float walkTime;
    private float walkCounter;
    public float waitTime;
    private float waitCounter;
    private int walkDirection;


    public Animator animator;

    void Start()
    {

         animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
         animator.SetBool("IsRunning", true);

        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        waitCounter = waitTime;
        walkCounter = walkTime;
        ChooseDirection();

    }

    void Update()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsRunning", isWalking);
        if (isWalking)
        {
            walkCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

            switch (walkDirection)
            {
                case 0:
                    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, moveSpeed);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(0, -moveSpeed);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0);
                    break;
            }
            if (walkCounter < 0)
            {
                isWalking = false;
                waitCounter = waitTime;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            waitCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            myRigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
            if (waitCounter < 0)
            {
                ChooseDirection();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ChooseDirection()
    {

        walkDirection = Random.Range(0, 4);
        isWalking = true;
        walkCounter = walkTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: So your movement is correct but just the animation doesn't show? Did you create an AnimationController with a transition from "idle" to "walking" or whatever? Also, do you trigger the transition? Also, it might help us more if you included a link to your tutorial and some Code where you think the issue is.

Comment: yes i set the blend tree for proper animation. i edited and paste the code i used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the animator reference on Start

```
public Animator animator;
void Start()
{
     //Assuming that the Animator is attached to the same Game Object as this script
     animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```

create a parameter (on this case, a bool called "IsRunning"), and set it when you starts run

```
animator.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
```

in your case, you probably want to update the state as your "isWalking" variable changes, so on Update

```
animator.SetBool("IsRunning", isWalking);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. but i dont if i did was right can you look at it again ? i edited the code.

Comment: create a new Animator Controller (Right click on Project>Animator Controller) and add a parameter too it (press the "+"
sign on the Animator), now you can make the logic of your state machine using it, something like
if this parameter is true, you go from this animation to that animation. and you set this parameter with your script.
this is a pretty basic thing, so a really i recommend you to watch the unity Animation Controller tutorial, it's really easy
to catch visually. https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/animation/animator-component?playlist=17099